# Does Twitter SDK using OAuth work for iOS3.0?

Tags: iphone, twitter

Can anyone please tell me if the latest twitter sdk(OAuth) works for iOS3.0 ? If it works only for iOS4, and my app is written for iOS3.0 then how can I communicate with twitter?

Thank you.

Comment: Which Twitter SDK? The only official one is a REST web service which, obviously, would work with any OS.

Answer (score 1):

There is no twitter sdk for iOS. OAuth is only a method to authenticate user to let them use your API. You can use any REST framework or library like [HTTPRiot](http://labratrevenge.com/httpriot/docs/) .
If the only thing that you want to achieve is share something on twitter I can recommend you [ShareKit](http://www.getsharekit.com/)

Comment: Thank u.My Problem is when i tried to run the application from the site http://icodeblog.com/2010/09/16/dealing-with-the-twitter-oauth-apocalypse/comment-page-1/#comment-15073,   it was giving errors, is that app work for ios3.0.

Comment: and i tried the sourcecode from HTTPRiot, this also giving errors.

Comment: I open the source code and I see that the base SDK is set to iOS 4.1 so if you're using an old sdk you get a "base sdk missing" error. I strongly advice to start develop with 4.x SDK and eventually set the deploy target to 3.0